# Does core Polymer 2.0 support two-way binding?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I seem to be having trouble getting two-way binding to work with Polymer 2.0.  I'm keeping things minimal, only using Polymer.Element.

I define a [parent component](https://github.com/bahrus/xtal/blob/master/tests/x-slick-grid/example1a-component.html):

```
<dom-module id="example1a-component">
  <template>
    <xtal-fetch req-url="generated.json" result="{{myFetchResult}}"></xtal-fetch>
    <div>fetch result: 
        <span>{{myFetchResult}}</span>
    </div>
  </template>


  <script>
    class Example1a extends Polymer.Element{
        static get is(){return 'example1a-component'}
        static get properties(){
            return {
                myFetchResult :{
                    type: String
                }
            }
        }
    }
    customElements.define(Example1a.is, Example1a)
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

The [fetch class](https://github.com/bahrus/xtal/blob/master/src/xtal-fetch.js) looks like:

```
       class XtalFetch extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() { return 'xtal-fetch'; }
        static get properties() {
            return {
                debounceTimeInMs: {
                    type: Number
                },
                reqInfo: {
                    type: Object,
                },
                reqInit: {
                    type: Object
                },
                reqUrl: {
                    type: String,
                    observer: 'loadNewUrl'
                },
                /**
                * The expression for where to place the result.
                */
                result: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    readOnly: true
                },
            };
        }
        loadNewUrl() {
            debugger;
        }
        ready() {
            if (this.reqUrl) {
                const _this = this;
                fetch(this.reqUrl).then(resp => {
                    resp.text().then(txt => {
                        _this['_setResult'](txt);
                        _this['result'] = txt;
                        _this.notifyPath('result');
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
    elements.XtalFetch = XtalFetch;
    customElements.define(xtal.elements.XtalFetch.is, xtal.elements.XtalFetch);
```

Note that I am trying everything I can think of:

```
_this['_setResult'](txt);
_this['result'] = txt;
_this.notifyPath('result');
```

I see the result of the the fetch going into the result property of the fetch element, not into the parent.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. Make sure to call `super` when you're overriding a method:

```
ready() {
  super.ready(); // <-- important!
  ...
}
```

That's enough to make your code work ([demo](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/jBaWjb?editors=1010)).

This is easy to forget, so the `polymer-linter` was recently updated to [warn users about this](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-linter/issues/52).