# Does two-way binding with Polymer [2] only work with Polymer elements?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have defined a Polymer element, `<xtal-fetch>`, which, [thanks to previous help on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839652/does-core-polymer-2-0-support-two-way-binding), is able to pass the results to the containing Polymer element via Polymer's two-way binding support.

But I'm finding that it doesn't seem to pass the results to a native custom element.

Source code is [here](https://github.com/bahrus/xtal/blob/master/tests/xtal-fetch.test1.html), and you can test it [here](https://rawgit.com/bahrus/xtal/master/tests/xtal-fetch.test1.html).

If I'm not missing anything, is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in the title: As long as the data binding is done within a Polymer host element, you could use Polymer data binding with native web components.

But it seems you're trying to use Polymer data binding inside the constructor of a native element (i.e., [`<fetch-container>`'s `innerHTML` uses Polymer data binding syntax](https://github.com/bahrus/xtal/blob/eabf217/tests/fetch-container.js#L8)). That won't work because you're not in a Polymer host element. If you convert `<fetch-container>` to a Polymer element, you would then be able to use Polymer's data binding. If you otherwise prefer to use the native element, you'd have to manually setup the data binding in your element by adding an event listener on the `result-changed` event of `<xtal-fetch>`.

Comment: You understood my question the way I intended, in the "That won't work" clause.  I understand two-way data flow is not something all frameworks / developers universally support.  Personally, I think it is useful, in order to avoid code boilerplate (having to add listeners).  IMHO, I would think it should be something web component libraries ought to be able to "opt-in" to somehow, without having to extend a Polymer element.  Especially if there's a clean way for  Polymer to find the containing custom element.